# Selenium: ChromeDriver can find an element HtmlUnitDriver can't

Tags: java, selenium

So, my program waits for 7 seconds then finds an element. ChromeDriver can manage this task well though HtmlUnitDriver fails at this:

```
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7+r, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        By e = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"showSkip\"]/a");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(e);
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
```

That code works great, this doesn't hower:

```
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7+r, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        By e = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"showSkip\"]/a");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(e);
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
```

And that spits out this sad error:

http://pastebin.com/AWzFrL2n

I need to use HtmlDriverUnit because one of my servers cannot install chrome.

Comment: Is the element you are trying to find is placed by javascript? If yes, don't forget to enable javascript in HtmlUnitDriver when initializing it -> driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

Comment: I've played around with that before, however that causes the same error.

Comment: Are the tag and attributenames written with lowercase in the source of the page? HtmlUnitDriver's xpath is case-sensitive, so for example //a is not the same as //A. Also, do you get the expected source when you display the source of HtmlUnitDriver (possible useragent issue)?

Comment: This is horrible. HtmlUnit doesn't even print the page: http://pastebin.com/E0yRfhWx ChromeDriver doesn't do that.

Comment: Infact it doesn't even get the title or anything/..

Comment: Try to initialize HtmlUnitDriver like "new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOXZZ)" where ZZ is some HtmlUnit version dependent number (you will get some list of the available values I guess)

Comment: That seems to have fixed that, but now when I try and click a button using javascript (this works on chrome), it doesn't work with the firefox setup you mentioned:

This code: http://pastebin.com/TukFM2sQ creates this stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/EhWbD0uk

That exception isn't descriptive enough to help me fix it.

Comment: @skandigraun How would I fix the above?

Comment: Also be aware that the HtmlUnitDriver's JavaScript engine is different than the major browsers, and that can causes some issues. See: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver